# How to enforce uniqueness of 2 MongoDB fields in combination?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I currently have a `Comment` MongoDB table where I enforce uniqueness of a `remote_id` field.

[The MongoDB documentation is here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/).

I am now in a situation where the `remote_id` attribute should only be unique for the user that owns the comment. In other words:

- The `User` **Peter** can only have 1 `Comment` with `remote_id` **123**
- The `User` **John** can only have 1 `Comment` with `remote_id` **123**
- The `Users` **Peter** and **John** can both have 1 `Comment` with `remote_id` **123**

**How do I enforce uniqueness of 2 fields in combination?**

My table is defined in a model file within my Ruby on Rails application, and it currently looks like this:

```
class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :datetime,          type: Time
  field :remote_id,         type: String

  index({ remote_id: 1 },   { unique: true })
  index({ user_id: 1 },     { background: true })

  belongs_to :user,         :inverse_of => :comments
end
```

Comment: I have no idea about Ruby whatsoever, but what you are looking for is called a unique compound index and is createe with `db.collection.ensureIndex({user_id:1,remote_id:1},{unique:true})` in the mongo shell.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Mongoid's `index` call is pretty much directly translated to `ensureIndex` so `index(x)` ends up as `ensureIndex(x)`. You're pretty close to an answer even without knowing Ruby.

Comment: Hi both. Thanks for pitching in. But is what you guys are saying maybe that the index in my code that is currently `index({ remote_id: 1 },   { unique: true })` could instead be `index({ remote_id: 1, user_id: 1 },   { unique: true })` ?

Comment: Yeah, that should work. I'd more comfortable if Markus answered though.

Comment: I just tested, and it worked. Thanks guys. Feel free to put it in as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following line to you model

```
validates :remote_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user }
```

also for completeness :
if you want to validate uniqueness of more than 2 fields

(for example if you want the **comment to be unique per user per post**) use the following

```
validates :remote_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:user, :post] }
```

assuming that the comment has a `post` field or relation.

Comment: Hi @artmees. I have chosen `index({ remote_id: 1, user_id: 1 }, { unique: true })` instead.

Comment: I prefer using the validates cause it's looks better, more readable, and add the correct errors to the form in case you are using something like `RailsAdmin`, but it's your call